# Android Studio IDE Update

Tags: android, android-studio

Scenario is,

I have installed Android Studio `version 1.5.1`, I want to update it to `2.1.2`

I have downloaded patch file (size 412 MiB) from stable channel. Problem is that (may be my confusion) I have two android studio versions on my system now.When I click `setup64.exe` in patch file `bin` folder, its opens `android studio 2.1.2` and when I click android studio from my Start menu shortcut,it open old version 1.5.1. Whats the matter? Adnroid studio did not behave like this in past on updation?

Comment: Yeah it's fine, some versions of studio is installed in separately

Comment: You can remove AS `version 1.5.1` and use `2.1.2`.

Comment: They sharing same sdk, When I try to remove 1.5.1, it also uninstall sdk and many other problems occurs

Comment: SDK is in different folder of AS. If you don't mind, you can update the soft link of the shortcut (in Start menu) to `2.1.2` and forget `1.5.1`.

Comment: @thuongle how I can remove 'version 1.5.1', when I click uninstall.exe of it, it also removes sdk. I have tried  and If I copy all files of patch file to old version place then it does not work in this case too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It happens because the Android Studio can be saved multiple copies in your disk. It is to say you have two `android-studio` folders now, which represents the `version 1.5.1` and `version 2.1.2`. You can just delete the folder that represent `version 1.5.1` and find the `studio64.exe` in your `version 2.1.2` folder and right-click the file then choose to send it to start menu. By the way, the SDK can also be saved multiple copies. You can choose which sdk to use in your Android Studio's settings. And if you use AS in windows platform, there are three kinds of package you can choose. One of these you can just unzip the package to use AS instead of installing. Here is the link to download:https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html

Comment: its not easy for me to delete `version 1.5.1`. When I delete, it also demage sdk or some files

Comment: @ZaidMirza you can choose the `android-studio-ide-xxxx-windows.zip` version. No Android SDK and no installer. It makes your AS and sdk all alone. Next time if you unintall the AS, you just unintall the AS, the sdk is still there.

Comment: thanks for sharing information, your answer is more comprehensive

Comment: @ZaidMirza Enjoy your coding! :)

Answer (score 0):

Because your Start Menu icon is of version 1.5.1. Just replace it with 2.1.2.
and the reason behind it as the upper versions has more functionalities than previous one so developer can use both one as per requirements.

Comment: is it not will increase burden on system by having two versions?

Comment: No  until you run both the version.it works as a separate setups.

Comment: yes they can share same sdk. and you can assign them different one too.

Comment: its mean Patch files just includes updates for IDE,not for SDK. SDK come along with full download only

Comment: yes it updates studio version only,if you want to update sdk versions then you have to update it via sdk manager in the android studio.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your knowlegde